# How can i add attribute to a textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, textbox, custom-attributes

i have a datalist in which i have a text box name txtvoteoption now on i add attributes on item data-bound on this text box but now i want to add the third attribute using java script ?

the reason behind i want this on java script because  i have a drop down on this page also which change using drop down and i want to add this attribute on this change event

this code which is working fine on item data-bound event

```
txtVoteOption.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "EnableTip('" + txtVoteOption.ClientID + "','text',1);");
            txtVoteOption.Attributes.Add("onblur", "DisableTip('" + txtVoteOption.ClientID + "','text');");
            txtVoteOption.Attributes.Add("validation", "Required,Please enter option A,default.png;4");
```

i tried but its not working this is javascript code.

```
   var txtOption1=document.getElementById("ctl00_cphContent_dlVoteOption_ctl01_txtVoteOption");
  alert(txtOption1);
  txtOption1.attributes.add('validation', 'Required,Please enter option A,default.png;4');
```

Comment: What does the *.Attributes.Add* function do? You should not be adding non-standard HTML attributes or DOM node properties.

Comment: i already mention in above code that this code is server side code in c# which on item databound event of datalist.which working fine for me ,but now i have to accomplish this task from javascript

Comment: No, you didn't but thanks for clarifying in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the first example it seems you use some kind of framework. In the second you don't.

`txtOption1.attributes` returns a [**`NamedNodeMap`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NamedNodeMap). It does not have a method `add`.

You have to use [**`element.setAttribute`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) and then access it with [**`element.getAttribute`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).

You should also consider using [HTML5 `data` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) for compatibility. Avoid adding any other kind of self defined attributes. Every element has a well defined set of allowed attributes.

Comment: i go through the url you posted here of mozilla.and i did that exact things but when i use firebug its does not show me the custom attribute which i have add using this code.

Comment: var txtOption1=document.getElementById("ctl00_cphContent_dlVoteOption_ctl01_txtVoteOption");    
      txtOption1.attributes.setNamedItem("validation","Required,Please enter option A,default.png;4");

Comment: thanks Felix Kling its working me . i am just making a small mistake but its now work for me.

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Works well for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/y4ZuR/ Firebug shows the attribute.